# I cannot call a function from my HTML button in my module Javascript file

Tags: javascript, function, module

The problem I am having is that my JavaScript file is becoming to big for me to work, so now I am using modules to make my code cleaner and easier for me to read. The problem is that I have a button in my HTML page that when clicked I want it to run my function in my script file. The file has the type module for my linked script files. But for some reason the browser keeps saying that my function is not defined. I have tried many things and the only way to get it to work is to get rid of the type="module". Is there a way to keep my JavaScript file module and still call a function from the DOM? I have triple checked my
spelling and curly brackets but it does not work.

Here is the html and JavaScript code below:

Here is the HTML Button

```
 <button type="button" name="button" onclick="start()" class="sub" id="hover">Request a Quote</button>
```

Here is the HTML Script tags

```
<script src="scripts/page.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/second.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="scripts/main.js"></script> //this is the script I want to access
```

Javascript

```
//these are the imports for all included files
import { schval } from './script'


function start(){

    function valSnapFrameSchedules(){
        schval();
          if (schval() === true){
            alert("this came as true");
          }
    }

}
```

Here is the error code I get:

```
Paused on exception
ReferenceError: start is not defined
```

Comment: Why is it `type="module"` ? That would be your issue.

Comment: modules live in a separate context - use `document.getElementById('hover').addEventListener('click', start)` in `scripts/main.js`

Comment: -Jaromanda X Thank you so much you are a genius, I did not even think of that. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .js in the import line:

```
import { schval } from './script.js'
```

This error shows up when we set the `type="module` to the script line.

You can also check this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-can-t-my-html-file-find-the-javascript-function-from-a-sourced-module

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which I prefer:

in your `main.js` add the following:

```
const hoverElement = document.getElementById('hover');
hoverElement.addEventListener('click', start);


function start(){

    function valSnapFrameSchedules(){
        schval();
          if (schval() === true){
            alert("this came as true");
          }
    }

    valSnapFrameSchedules() // calling this function was missing in your code!

}
```

In your HTML file, you don't need to add `onClick`, so simply remove `onclick="start()"`

```
 <button type="button" name="button" class="sub" id="hover">Request a Quote</button>
```

In this way, you don't need to access the function in the module from the HTML file.